# Create a text with image magick

Tags: command, imagemagick, imagick

I am trying to create an image file which has a text and a transparent background.

I used this command:

```
convert -background black -fill blue \ -font Arial -pointsize 72 label: \ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam invidunt ut labore . invidunt ut labore . output.png
```

but it did not create me anything and I got this error / message:

> convert.exe: unable to open image '\': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image '\': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'Lorem': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'ipsum': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'dolor': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'sit': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'amet': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'consetetur': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'sadipscing': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'elitr': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'sed': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'diam': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'nonumy': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'eirmod': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'tempor': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'invidunt': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'ut': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'labore': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'et': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'dolore': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'magna': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'aliquyam': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'invidunt': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'ut': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'labore': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image '.': Permission denied @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'invidunt': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'ut': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image 'labore': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe:
>   unable to open image '.': Permission denied @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this
>   image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert.exe: no
>   images defined `output.png' @
>   error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3235.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
convert -background black -fill blue -font Arial -pointsize 72 label:"Lorem ipsum" output.png
```

[image]

Comment: Yes - so that ImageMagick knows where your label starts and ends.

Answer (score 0):

C:\OPV2\binaries\FontToImage\convert.exe label:"abcd" C:\OPv2\test.png
convert.exe: unable to open image 'label:abcd': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3491.
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/556.
convert.exe: no images defined`C:\OPv2\test.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3300.

Quite strange, isn't it ?
On my local computer, it's working file

C:\OPV2\binaries\FontToImage\convert.exe --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-23 Q16 x64 2019-01-02 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Visual C++: 180040629
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raw rsvg tiff webp xml zlib

label is not reconized ...

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please consider editing and formatting your answer so that its easier for everyone to understand. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help.